# Будет ли сильно влиять на скорость запрос?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php, sql

Будет ли сильно влиять на скорость если я сделаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE IN(p1,p2,p3 ... ,p50)
```

Или такую выборку можно записать по другому?

Comment: а попробовать не пробовали? Или вы изучаете sql исключительно "в уме", без использования компьютера и СУБД?

Comment: Можно еще каждое условие записать через OR. Но что будет быстрее надо смотреть на конкретных данных

Comment: Только не забывайте про кеширование =)

Comment: Индекс еще можно добавить на то поле которое в where участвует.

Comment: Вращаю барабан, ставлю на то, что нужен банальный джойн.

Comment: Нет, не нужен. Просто есть миссив с номерами, и по их нужно выбрать записи

Comment: если сделать такой запрос, то mysql ругнется на ошибку синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем запросе после предиката WHERE надо указать поле по которому фильтруем данные на пример

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2,10,22,196,1541);
```